# How to add new module to apache2 Centos6

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

When I compiled apache I forget to add `proxy_http_module` how can I add it now?

My apache is installed here: `/usr/local/apache2`

I tried to compile again and get this error:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/httpd-2.2.31/support'
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/httpd-2.2.31'
/root/httpd-2.2.31/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -g -O2 -pthread        -I. -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/os/unix -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/server/mpm/prefork -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/http -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/filters -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/proxy -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/include -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/generators -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/mappers -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/database -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/srclib/apr/include -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/srclib/apr-util/include -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/server -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/proxy/../generators -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/ssl -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/dav/main -fPIE -prefer-non-pic -static -c modules.c && touch modules.lo
gcc -g -O2 -pthread        -I. -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/os/unix -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/server/mpm/prefork -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/http -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/filters -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/proxy -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/include -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/generators -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/mappers -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/database -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/srclib/apr/include -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/srclib/apr-util/include -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/server -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/proxy/../generators -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/ssl -I/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/dav/main -fPIE -c /root/httpd-2.2.31/server/buildmark.c
/root/httpd-2.2.31/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -g -O2 -pthread   -pie     -o httpd  modules.lo buildmark.o -export-dynamic server/libmain.la modules/http/libmod_http.la modules/mappers/libmod_so.la server/mpm/prefork/libprefork.la os/unix/libos.la -lm -lpcre /root/httpd-2.2.31/srclib/apr-util/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat /root/httpd-2.2.31/srclib/apr/libapr-1.la -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: server/.libs/libmain.a(main.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
server/.libs/libmain.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [httpd] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/httpd-2.2.31'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

here is my conf:

```
./configure --with-mpm=prefork --with-included-apr --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-so --enable-pie --enable-cgi --with-pcre --enable-ssl --enable-rewrite --enable-vhost-alias --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-http --enable-proxy-ftp --enable-proxy-balancer --enable-cache --enable-mem-cache --enable-file-cache --enable-disk-cache --disable-spelling --enable-dav --enable-ldap --enable-authnz-ldap --enable-authnz-ldap --enable-authn-anon --enable-authn-alias --build=i686
```

Comment: Compile it again?

Comment: I updated main post please check...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it's included under apache sources, IMO the easiest way is to go to the sources directory you used, reconfigure it adding mod_proxy and then make install. It does not overwrite your configuration files.

Be sure to do a `make clean` before recompiling

As a sidenote, i suggest you to enable all modules as shared.

Another method when you are using out of tree modules is using apxs which you can find in your installation directory, but in your case it seems easier to recompile/

Comment: I updated main post please check...

Comment: added a note on my reply about make clean before make

Comment: Now error changed to this: `make[4]: *** [mod_authnz_ldap.slo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/aaa'
make[3]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules/aaa'
make[2]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/httpd-2.2.31/modules'
make[1]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/httpd-2.2.31'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
`

Comment: Seems you've enabled all modules now. There should be some more lines before the ones you posted but blindly, i suppose you miss some devel libraries that are neccessary for some module. Seeing ldap in there maybe you need openldap-devel or such. Or you can exclude this module if you dont plan using it.

Comment: I removed ldap and compiled but now I get this error: `Syntax error on line 56 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so: undefined symbol: ap_proxy_location_reverse_map`

Comment: You have to load both mod_proxy and mod_proxy http, in that order, so:
`LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so`
`LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so`

Comment: Thanks, now I get new error: `Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration` is there any way to load all installed modules with one command?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925528/invalid-command-order-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module-not-included
Nope, no command that loads all required modules, but google helps